# Dehumidifier is draining through a hose and through a second opening into the bucket

Tags: hose, dehumidifier

We bought a GE 35 pint Dehumidifier in June 2022,  and attached a clear hose 3 days ago.  The hose connection is dry and tight and water does flow through the tube but it also drains into the bucket through a smaller opening near the hose connection.  In the photo below, the hose connection is on the left (hose removed).  The smaller opening on the front is where we are getting water discharge in addition to water coming out the hose.  What is the purpose of this smaller opening and how can I ensure water will only drain through the hose?  This smaller opening is not described or pictured in the owner's manual.

[image: hose connection and second drain opening]

Comment: I have a dehumidifier which intermittently behaves in the way you describe. I haven't looked inside as you have, but I assume it's got the same 'secondary' outlet into the bucket. I *think* what that's for is in case the hose is blocked it then 'overflows' into the bucket instead of filling up the innards of the machine. I see this behavior most often when the hose does not have a nice continuous slope out and away from the machine and instead allows some water to sit in a loop instead of draining.

Comment: How long is the hose you attached?

Comment: Both of those outlets have the bucket below them.  The hose is lowest and the port is slightly higher, like by 1/4”. It is there as the "emergency spillway" so water goes into the bucket if there is a problem with the hose.  The hose must slope downward leaving the machine and must never rise above the port.

Comment: Thanks, the hose does slope downward and is about 3' long at most.  It feeds into the condensate pump for the A/C which of course pumps it out of the house.

Comment: Is the "clear hose" abnormally small diameter .vs. a normal garden hose?